# Unmarshal Dynamic JSON

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I receive dynamic JSON from an API that follows this pattern:

```
{
    "ts": timestamp,
    "data": [
        [ code1, payload1 ],
        [ code2, payload2 ],
        ...
    ]
}
```

For example the raw data will be:

```
    var streamSnapshot = []byte(

`{ 
   "ts": 1496244373.04,
   "data":[
      ["xrate", {"rate":1.2916,"ccy":"USD"}],
      ["balance", 
         {
            "open_stake":["GBP", 0.0],
            "balance":["GBP", 0.0]
         }
      ],
      ["event", 
         {
            "competition_id":"545",
            "ir_status":"pre_event",
            "start_time":"2017-09-10T17:00:00+00:00",
            "competition_name":"USA NFL",
            "event_id":"2017-09-10,21617,21635",
            "home":"Buffalo Bills",
            "away":"New York Jets",
            "sport":"af",
            "competition_country":"US"
         }
      ],
      ["sync", {"Token":"eb1c57132d004f8d8fb967c076921fac"}]
   ]
}`)
```

Considering that we want to avoid unmarshalling to a struct like this:

```
type StreamMessage struct {
    Data [][]interface{} `json:"data"`
    Ts   float64         `json:"ts"`
}
```

where we would have to cast the data back like:

```
    m := raw.(map[string]interface{})

    switch messageType {
    case XRATE:
        xrate := XRate{
            Message: Message{
                Type:      XRATE,
                TimeStamp: msg.Ts,
            },
            rate: m["rate"].(float64),
            ccy:  m["ccy"].(string),
        }  
     ...
```

What would be the better way of unmarshalling this?

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type StreamMessage struct {
    Data []*Data `json:"data"`
    Ts   float64 `json:"ts"`
}

type Data struct {
    Type    string
    XRate   *XRateData
    Balance *BalanceData
    Event   *EventData
    Sync    *SyncData
}

func (d *Data) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    dec := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(b))
    t, _ := dec.Token()
    if delim, ok := t.(json.Delim); !ok || delim != '[' {
        return errors.New("expecting data to be an array")
    }

    if err := dec.Decode(&d.Type); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var err error
    switch d.Type {
    case "xrate":
        err = dec.Decode(&d.XRate)
    case "sync":
        err = dec.Decode(&d.Sync)
    case "balance":
        err = dec.Decode(&d.Balance)
    case "event":
        err = dec.Decode(&d.Event)
    default:
        return errors.New("unknown data type " + d.Type)
    }

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    t, _ = dec.Token()
    if delim, ok := t.(json.Delim); !ok || delim != ']' {
        return errors.New("expecting array to be two elements")
    }

    return nil
}

type XRateData struct {
    Rate json.Number `json:"rate"`
    CCY  string      `json:"ccy"`
}

type BalanceData struct {
    // TODO
}

type EventData struct {
    // TODO
}

type SyncData struct {
    Token string `json:"Token"`
}

var streamSnapshot = []byte(

    `{ 
   "ts": 1496244373.04,
   "data":[
      ["xrate", {"rate":1.2916,"ccy":"USD"}],
      ["balance", 
         {
            "open_stake":["GBP", 0.0],
            "balance":["GBP", 0.0]
         }
      ],
      ["event", 
         {
            "competition_id":"545",
            "ir_status":"pre_event",
            "start_time":"2017-09-10T17:00:00+00:00",
            "competition_name":"USA NFL",
            "event_id":"2017-09-10,21617,21635",
            "home":"Buffalo Bills",
            "away":"New York Jets",
            "sport":"af",
            "competition_country":"US"
         }
      ],
      ["sync", {"Token":"eb1c57132d004f8d8fb967c076921fac"}]
   ]
}`)

func main() {
    var sm StreamMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal(streamSnapshot, &sm); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(sm)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ktABS6z40m